# Issue with DynamicSvgNft Contract: getHighSVG() and getLowSVG() Functions Returning Incorrect Values

Tags: solidity, nft, contract-debugging, chainlink, openzeppelin-contracts

Hello   Stack Exchange community!
I am currently working on a project that involves an NFT contract called DynamicSvgNft. The contract is designed to change the SVG image URI of the NFT based on a price feed from Chainlink. However, I am facing an issue where the `getHighSVG()` and `getLowSVG()` functions are returning mixed-up values.
Here is the relevant code for the contract:

> // DynamicSvgNft.sol

```js
         contract DynamicSvgNft is ERC721, Ownable {
     uint256 private s_tokenCounter;
     string private s_lowImageURI;
     string private s_highImageURI;
     AggregatorV3Interface internal immutable i_priceFeed;
 
     mapping (uint256 => int256) private s_tokenToHighValue;
 
     event CreatedNft(uint256 indexed tokenId, int256 highValue);
 
     constructor(address priceFeedAddress, string memory lowSvg, string memory highSvg) ERC721("Dynamic SVG NFT", "DSN") {
         s_tokenCounter = 0;
         i_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
         s_lowImageURI = svgToImageUri(lowSvg);
         s_highImageURI = svgToImageUri(highSvg);
 
     }
 
     // functionalities
     
     function mintNft(int256 highValue) public {
         _safeMint(msg.sender, s_tokenCounter);
         s_tokenToHighValue[s_tokenCounter] = highValue;
          s_tokenCounter = s_tokenCounter + 1;
         emit CreatedNft(s_tokenCounter, highValue);
     }
 
     function svgToImageUri(string memory svg) public pure returns (string memory) {
         // convert the svgs to image uris and store them in variables for later use
         string memory baseURL = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
         string memory svgBase64Encoded = Base64.encode(bytes(string(abi.encodePacked(svg))));
         return string(abi.encodePacked(baseURL, svgBase64Encoded));
     }
 
 
     function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
         return "data:application/json;base64,";
     }
 
     function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
         if(!_exists(tokenId)) {
             revert ERC721Metadata__URI_QueryFor_NonExistentToken();
         } 
 
         (, int256 price, , , ) = i_priceFeed.latestRoundData();
 
         string memory imageURI;
         if (price >= s_tokenToHighValue[tokenId]) {
               imageURI = s_highImageURI;
         } else {
              imageURI = s_lowImageURI;
         }
         return
             string(
             abi.encodePacked(
                 _baseURI(),
                 Base64.encode(
                     bytes(
                         abi.encodePacked(
                             '{"name":"',
                             name(),
                             '", "description":"An NFT that changes based on the chainlink feed",',
                             '"attributes": [{"trait_type": "coolness", "value": 100}], "image":"',
                             imageURI,
                             '"}'
                         )
                     )
                 )
             )
             );
     }
     function getLowSVG()  public view returns (string memory) {
         return s_lowImageURI;
     }
       function getHighSVG()  public view returns (string memory) {
         return s_highImageURI;
     }
     function getTokenCounter() public view returns (uint256 ) {
         return s_tokenCounter;
     }
     function getPriceFeed() public view returns (AggregatorV3Interface) {
         return i_priceFeed;
     }
 }
```

And here is the test code where the issue is being observed:

> // DynamicSvgNft.test.js

```js
//imports

const highSVGImageUri = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCIgd2lkdGg9IjQwMCIgIGhlaWdodD0iNDAwIiB4bWxucz0";
    const lowSVGImageUri = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBzdGFuZGFsb25lPSJubyI/...";
!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  

? describe.skip
  : describe("Dynamic Svg Nft unit test", () => {
      let dynamicSvgNft, MockV3Aggregator, deployer;
      beforeEach(async () => {
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
        deployer = accounts[0];
        await deployments.fixture(["mocks", "dynamicsvg"]);
        dynamicSvgNft = await ethers.getContract("DynamicSvgNft");
        MockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract("MockV3Aggregator");
      });
    describe("Constructor", () => {
        it("sets the initial values correctly", async () => {
            const highSVG = await dynamicSvgNft.getHighSVG(); // Returns lowSVGImageUri instead of the highSVGImageUri
            const lowSVG = await dynamicSvgNft.getLowSVG();   // Returns the highSVGImageUri instead of the lowSVGImageUri
              // ... (assertions)
               console.log(`highSVG is => ${highSVG}`)
                assert.equal(highSVG, highSVGImageUri)
                console.log(`lowSVG is => ${lowSVG}`)
                assert.equal(lowSVG, lowSVGImageUri)
                assert.equal(tokenCounter.toString(), "0")
                assert.equal(priceFeed, MockV3Aggregator.address)
        });
    });
    })
    // ... (other test code)
```

> DynamicSvgNft.deploy.js

```js
    const { network } = require("hardhat");
    const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
    const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");
    const fs = require("fs")
    
    module.exports = async ({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
        const {deploy, log} = deployments
        const {deployer} = await  getNamedAccounts()
    
        const chainId = network.config.chainId
        let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress
    
        if(developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
            const EthUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
            ethUsdPriceFeedAddress  = EthUsdAggregator.address
        } else {
            ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId].ethUsdPriceFeed
        }
    
        log("#####################################");
    
        // read the nft images
        const lowSVG =  fs.readFileSync("images/dynamicNft/frown.svg", {encoding: "utf8"})
        const highSVG =  fs.readFileSync("images/dynamicNft/happy.svg", {encoding: "utf8"})
        args = [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress, highSVG, lowSVG]
    
        const dynamicSvgNft = await deploy("DynamicSvgNft", {
            from: deployer,
            args:args,
            log: true,
            waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
        })
    
        if(!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
            log("verifying.....")
            await verify(dynamicSvgNft.address, args)
            log("verified!")
    
            log("#########################################")
        }
    
    }
    module.exports.tags = ["all", "dynamicsvg", "main"]
```

The issue is that the `getHighSVG()` function is returning the value of `s_lowImageURI`, and vice versa, resulting in incorrect values being returned during the test

I have thoroughly reviewed the contract and test code, but I couldn't identify the root cause of the problem. I suspect that there might be an issue with the contract deployment or the `svgToImageUri` function used in the contract.

Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and fix this issue would be highly appreciated! If needed, I can also provide the full code for the contract and test files.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the hassle everyone, found the bug! I have already answered the question. check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76838053/22151593) hope this helps someone out. Cheers